# Was this character really the same character from before?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

While *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker* began to answer and definitely closed off certain aspects of The Skywalker Saga story, it also introduced a lot of elements from Legends and Lore, and left certain things seemingly ambiguous.

With that said, the marketing for this film was not shy about about the return of the series' biggest villain: the former Emperor, Supreme Chancellor of the Republic, and super manipulative Sith Lord, Darth Sidious.

But there are things mentioned or shown in the film that are curious:

> 1. While Sidious reveals he's Rey's grandfather, he also mentions that all of the Sith are with him (or that he is all of the Sith).
>
>  2. He is not fully formed and, at first, hangs on an apparatus.
>
>  3. He is found on the alleged Sith homeworld of Exegol (and there may have been statues of Darth Nilhilus present).
>
>  4. He mentions that he has "died before", and we may presume that a combination of dark side Force power and genetic manipulation have been involved, as there are containers full of Snokes!
>
>  5. There are not Sidious loyalists present, but rather "Sith" loyalists and a Sith fleet with Sith Troopers.
>
>  6. The opening crawl's first words are: "The Dead Speak!"

In addition, episode I’s title, *The **Phantom** Menace*, is meant to more specifically pertain to Darth Sidious, besides being able to also apply to the tragedy of Anakin Skywalker.

Also in the prequels, the Jedi comment that The Sith have returned. And although it's most likely that they are just referencing Darth Maul and Darth Sidious, it does suggest a possible awakening to the Sith generally, as opposed to just dealing with a master and his apprentice(s).

Thus, it almost seems that Sidious (or the Sidious in *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*) is a byproduct of *something **beyond** the previous Sidious*, or that perhaps Sidious himself was always answering to someone else? It feels like there is a door behind a door with the way the character was so elusively presented in this film.

**Is there any evidence from other upcoming projects or the executive producers that suggests that perhaps this Sidious isn’t exactly the same Darth Sidious as before?**

Comment: I assumed it was actually him brought back from the dead and that his malformed fingers were a remnant of his injuries when he was killed by Vader.

Comment: right, but what happens when one is brought back from the dead by "unnatural" means? Are they the same or do they come back altered?

Comment: Seems logical to assume Darth Sidious is *not* the same as all the Sith, and that though the Sith may be defeated and return in cycles, it’s not always been Sidious. It just so happens it’s Sidious who literally returned this time.

Comment: @oliver-clare My Q is not about him being like other Sith. My question is about if he's still really "the same exact" Darth Sidious, because it seems like he may of returned as something "beyond" Sidious, since he claims that he is "All of the Sith". It's the idea that one was brought back from the dead (by certain means) if they really would be the same (ie: Kahl Drogo in GOT came back as a zombie-nearly lifeless version of himself).

Comment: @DarthLocke indeed. In my comment I said I think it's unlikely Sidious is _literally_ all the Sith. In the same way Rey was not _all the Jedi_. Rey embodied the Jedi and, in the moment when it mattered most, they helped her defeat Sidious. The final stand-off between Rey & Ben and Sidious was chock-full of metaphors. I very-much doubt Sidious meant he was literally all of the Sith. I would answer your question: **"Yes, it was the same Sidious, altered only by his experience of death."** But I don't have any evidence, just my opinion :D

Comment: I see, but still disagree. I think the Sith is about corrupting the soul and so one's identity is reshaped semi-internally through unnatural death rituals (Darth Vader 2017+ comic) and that with Jedi it is about having the force work with you externally--it's not trying to shape you from the inside out, but the outside in. With the Sith I think it's the opposite. It's why they have to "bleed" kyber crystals for instance. Everything about the Sith is very Gothic Lit and that is about literal transformations...

Comment: I feel like this question is asking for logic where there is none to be found.

Comment: @ruffdove The TV Series (Mando, Bad Batch, etc) and some of the upcoming books (Shadow of the Sith) may be shedding more light on the semantics of what things really are/how things happened. So my Q may finally be answered at some point! :D

Comment: Possibly, Darth Locke, and for your sake I hope it is. But when if it is answered it will be as part of Disney's literary effort to retcon explanations for the screen writers' poor creative choices, not something that was meant all along. :)